# Performance implications when using "_var" over "_" in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

There's a general rule to name any unused variables with an `_` in Elixir. Doing so stops anything being bound to that variable.

However I have noticed a widely used pattern of prefixing with an underscore to denote an ignored argument, in the form of `_tail` (with the intention being to provide a hint as to what the variable would be).

This is encouraged by the language via a warning in the shell if you try to then access `_tail`:

> warning: the underscored variable "_tail" is used after being set. A leading underscore indicates that the value of the variable should be ignored. If this is intended please rename the variable to remove the underscore

But here's the catch; `_tail` has the variable bound to it, whereas when using just `_` it does not.

Does this mean that there's a performance penalty when naming ignored variables with anything other than an `_`? Or does Elixir still bind `_` behind the scenes, and just error on any attempt to access?

**Edit:** It looks like the Erlang compiler specifically optimizes this case to treat `_*` as `_` and thus there is no overhead, source: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html

Comment: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." --Donald Knuth. Worry about a performance penalty when you find a problem with performance in your code and not before.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'm more interested in how it works rather than using it for improving performance at the moment. Generally I agree with the quote you used, however not worrying about something until it becomes a problem is quite an ignorant way to work. For example; I would probably never learn the answer to this question, as I doubt anything would warrant looking at performance this closely.

Comment: Premature optimization is truly the ignorant way to work. But if you want to understand how this works "under the hood"--why not just look at the Elixir source?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci so... generally, how do you draw a line as to what is premature? Say I'm working with a LinkedList (in Java) which is being heavily updated and having specific elements accessed, and I switch to using an ArrayList. I doubt anyone would call this a premature optimization, but why not? Probably because it's seen as the more "correct" way to do it in the language. Well, same applies here. Why force a potential performance timebomb on yourself if you can avoid it right now?

Comment: It's premature if you don't have working code and you haven't profiled anything.  Until you actually try something and see there's a performance issue you're just guessing.  And developers (at least in my experience) are bad at guessing where the performance bottlenecks will actually be. Get it working right, then make it pretty, then worry about fast--if your customer complains.

Comment: And by the way, switching from a linked list to an array would be a premature optimization because what if the customer decides they need some feature that will require lots of insertions at random points?  You're just guessing about the future in either case so any guess will work equally well.  There's no point in optimizing something that you don't know yet.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci totally agree if your code isn't working that it's not worth it. The process you described, I'm basically at the end stage of making it fast - but the customer is myself (side project). That's what lead me to ask the question above - but only because I got to wondering what it different it actually makes (if any), rather than suspecting it of any particular issue.

Comment: BTW there is some discussion of _var vs. _ in this thread from the Elixir Core mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elixir-lang-core/underscore/elixir-lang-core/EQxjThw8WHw/r0ZLZTKH7l4J  I'm not sure it's what you're looking for but FWIW.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I did misunderstand the nature of your question then @zackehh.  My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given everyone already gave the disclaimer to not worry about this kind of performance behaviour, the answer is: if a variable is not used, the compiler will notice it and the compiled bytecode will simply ignore it, as if you used `_`. That's the same reason why if you do `x = 1` and never `x`, you get a compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.  I hoped someone with more ability to speak to the underlying mechanics would add a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed there's special behaviour in Erlang (and hence Elixir) for the `_` variable.
But unless you measured that this is a performance problem for your application, I wouldn’t worry too much about this. I imagine overhead of binding variables would be completely insignificant if you're doing anything interesting inside the function.

Comment: I'm not really asking for personal use, I'm more interested in the behaviour pattern - e.g. is "_tail" treated the same as "_"?

Comment: Just noticed my comment was butchered by markdown :) `_tail` treated the same as `_` :)

Comment: No, it is not. `_tail` is treated exactly the same as any other variable (besides `_`). You could say that the leading underscore only controls compiler warnings.